# How can I detect keyboard and/or mouse input on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, windows-ce, keyboard-hook

I'm working on a small C++ project which involves a launcher application that does a bit of setup work and then invokes the real application. To be precise, I'm working on the launcher application - the real application is done by a separate team. These programs are both deployed to Windows Mobile devices. Now, I'd like to be able to get notified of all keyboard and mouse activity in the real application (which my launcher starts) - and I cannot modify the real application to do this.

On Windows desktop machines I'd do this using the [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx)  API. However, this is unavailable on Windows Mobile.

I also considered subclassing all windows in the process so that I can handle the relevant window messages for keyboard and mouse input - but I don't know how to get notified of new windows which the real process creates.

Does anybody have some thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SetWindowsHookEx, it is only undocumented. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/raffael/setwindowshookex-on-windows-mobile) is a good post about hooks and subclassing on Windows Mobile.